# Timeout expired error for report viewer in asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, report, viewer

i have 4 report viewer controls in my application in the same .aspx page and 3 of them display fine but fourth one always give following message when page loads first time

An error occurred during local report processing.
An error has occurred during report processing.
Cannot create a connection to data source 'DataSet_Audit_Trail_Events'.
Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
The wait operation timed out

Any ideas how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

N/A

Comment: Looks like a connection to the data source (database?) could not be established.  Check the connection details.

Comment: I have verified connection and it seems fine , same connection i am using for other three reports.

Comment: Can you post your code?